# AWS Batch CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: unable to find user alex5rps: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: bash, docker, aws-batch

I have a simple dockerized `"hello world"` `bash` script that I would like to run on `AWS Batch` though I am always getting this error:

> CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: unable to find
> user alex5rps: no matching entries in passwd file

When I go to change the job description I have these options though there is nothing to insert my docker password in it.

**Screenshot**
[image: the option I am referring to]

How can I properly set up a user to run this image on the AWS batch?

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /myScript

COPY ./test.sh .

RUN chmod +x ./test.sh
# Set the entrypoint to the script with CMD arguments

CMD ["./test.sh"]
```

and this is my
`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Hello World"
```

Comment: Do you need to set a non-root user? e.g. can you use a username of root within the container? That user usually always exists.

Comment: What is the content of `test.sh`? I think this file's content is very relevant for this question to be answered. Where does the username "alex5rps" come from?

Comment: Hi @NickODell , it is not that I require it it is just that when I use the default one I get this `CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::222385990452:assumed-role/AWSBatchHello/1d6f2b84d1d844fab09ec7e22d8805ce is not a` and unfortunately the error is not even fully displayed :(

Comment: Hi @knittl I have just updated the question with the content of `test.sh` . That username is the same that I use in my docker, I thought it was the only way to avoid this error `CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::222385990452:assumed-role/AWSBatchHello/1d6f2b84d1d844fab09ec7e22d8805ce is not a`

Comment: I don't know AWS batch, but it sounds/looks like you would need to add that user to your Docker image, no? `useradd` is a CLI tool to add user accounts on a GNU+Linux system.